# unable to toggle radiobutton in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to toggle a radiobutton in react. here is my logic.

```
const [selectedValue1, setSelectedValue1] = React.useState(false);

 const handleChange1 = event => {
if (state.selectedValue1 === false) {
      setSelectedValue1(true);

    } else {
      setSelectedValue1(false);
    }

    console.log(state.selectedValue1);
  };
```

Comment: Consider appending the rest of component code (JSX part, especially)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to take advantage of the `event` object that you have available.

You could do something as simple as:

```
const handleChange1 = event => setSelectedValue1(event.target.checked)
```

Assuming of course, that your JSX looks something like the following:

```
<input
    type="radio"
    name="group"
    onChange={handleChange1}
    checked={selectedValue1}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use something like this

```
const handleChange1 = () => { setSelectedValue1(!state.selectedValue1); };
```